# Excel Dynamic Array to include blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, dynamic-arrays

Is there a way to keep the empty cells when filtering data with the `FILTER()` function? As for now, Excel is outputing the value 0 when an empty cell occurs.

For Example if this is a table in Excel (named tbl):

```
Name  | City  | Street
----------------------
name1 | city1 | street1
name2 | city1 |
```

The function:

```
=FILTER(tbl;tbl[City]="city1")
```

Returned as above but with "0" instead of an empty cell.

Comment: You can apply format to resulting cells to hide zero value cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, since I solved it myself and there may be more people having the same issue.

You can use:

```
=FILTER(IF(tbl="";"";tbl);tbl[City]="city1")
```

To get an empty cell instead of a "0".